# How to append a filename with an index number

Tags: file-rename, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files (not more than 100) with different names, that I need to index at the end of the filename.
For example:

```
bla_1.txt
bla_2.txt
test_1.txt
unicorn_5.txt
```

should become:

```
bla_1_1.txt
bla_2_2.txt
test_1_3.txt
unicorn_5_4.txt
```

So, the problem is, that all the files have different names and already contain a number. I need to keep this old filename and just extend it with an index at the end of the name.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd %tmp%
mkdir index
pushd index
for /L %%N in (1,1,10) do echo >file_%%N.txt

dir
pause

set index=1
for %%F in (*) do (
 echo ren %%F %%~nF_[!index!].%%~xF
 set /A index+=1
)

popd
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for the script. I tried to run it, but all it does is creating a new folder with 10 files that have the index number 1-10 and contain the text "ECHO is switched off (OFF)". Am I doing something wrong after the part "pause" in the script? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using python, myself.

```
import os

path = 'D:/Append_Index'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 1

for file in files:
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, filename + "_" + str(i) +
file_extension))
i = i+1
```

This will put an index-number on everything in the folder "Append_Index", so I am sure, it's not the best solution, but it serves my purpose. And I am a beginner, anyways. Mabye it will someone else as well.